# Given a second order differential equation, write an equivalent system of first order equations with transformations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given a second order differential equation

$$y''+f(y)y'+g(y)=0,$$

write an equivalent system of first order equations with transformations

$$x_{1}=y,x_{2}=y'+\int_{0}^{y}f(s)ds.$$

This is what I did:

$$x_{1}'=y'=x_{2}-\int_{0}^{y}f(s)ds=x_{2}-\int_{0}^{x_{1}}f(s)ds$$

$$x_{2}'=y''+f(y)=-f(y)y'-g(y)+f(y)=f(y)(1-y')-g(y)=f(x_{1})(1-x_{2}+\int_{0}^{x_{1}}f(s)ds)-g(x_{1})$$

I feel like this answer is wrong though, because I am not sure if I'm doing the standard procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a second-order, generally non-linear, ordinary differential equaition of the form

$y'' + f(y)y' + g(y) = 0, \tag 1$

and the specified transformation of variables

$x_1 = y, \tag 2$

$x_2 = y' + \displaystyle \int_0^y f(s) \; ds, \tag 3$

we need to find $x_1'$ and $x_2'$; we start with the obvious

$x_1' = y', \tag 4$

and writing (3) in the form

$y' = x_2 - \displaystyle \int_0^y f(s) \; ds, \tag 5$

we further transform (4) to

$x_1' = x_2 - \displaystyle \int_0^y f(s) \; ds = x_2 - \displaystyle \int_0^{x_1} f(s) \; ds; \tag 6$

turning now to $x_2'$, we differentiate (3), 
applying the [***Leibniz integral rule***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to

$\displaystyle \int_0^y f(s) \; ds, \tag 7$

and find

$x_2' = y'' + f(y)y'; \tag 8$

we then write (1) in the form

$y'' = -f(y)y' - g(y) \tag 9$

and substitute this into (8) to obtain

$x_2' = y'' + f(y)y'$
$= -f(y)y' - g(y) + f(y)y' = -g(y) = -g(x_1); \tag{10}$

then the system (6), (10) is the transformed version of (1).

***Going the other way:***

we start with (6),

$x_1' = x_2 - \displaystyle \int_0^{x_1} f(s) \; ds, \tag 9$

and (10),

$x_2' = -g(x_1); \tag{10}$

using (2) and (3), and th Leibniz rule again,

$y'' = x_1'' = x_2' - f(x_1)x_1'$
$= -g(x_1) - f(x_1)x_1' = -g(y) - f(y)y', \tag{11}$

that is,

$y'' + f(y)y' + g(y) = 0, \tag{12}$

our original equation (1).

[Given a second order differential equation, write an equivalent system of first order equations with transformations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3392335/given-a-second-order-differential-equation-write-an-equivalent-system-of-first)